# Delete lines beginning and ending with a digit

Tags: sed, tr

I'm stuck - piping a text file like this:

`cat file1.txt | sed '/^[0-9].*[0-9]$/d' > file2.txt`

This regex catches the lines in a text editor, and it works when I use it to delete all blank lines in the same file, so no problem with (Linux/Windows) newline format I guess.

I wonder why this does not delete those lines, or how this can be done otherwise?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @cuonglm: sorry for not being clear enough; edited now.

Comment: I don't understand the question, the sed command works. But I don't understand your second sentence. "This regex catches the lines in a text editor" what text editor? "it works when I use it to delete all blank lines" blank lines? I thought its about begin and end with a digit? You may need to give example input and desired output.

Comment: Has the source data file come from a Windows system? If so, `[0-9]` will not match the last character on a line.

Comment: @chaos ; no the sed command above doesn't work although I can search and replace / delete lines using the same regex, i.e. `^[0-9].*[0-9]$` in a text editor like gedit or kkedit.

Comment: Then there is something with your file. I tested the sed command. Can you please post the output of `file file1.txt`?

Comment: @roaima ; I also tried [[:digit:]] but made no difference, but when I further looked into the newline issue, I've found that it was the cause! Thanks anyway : -)

Comment: @chaos ; thanks, what's wrong with this file is it's originally created under Windows I guess. I carefully deleted all the visible characters in a line and saw that `sed '/^\s*$/d'`deletes empty lines, so I thought it wasn't a newline issue; but I was wrong as I've just discovered. This works: `sed "/^[0-9].*\s*.*[0-9][$|\r]/d"` **Thank you all** for helping me find my way : -)

Comment: In your command you have a [uuoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extra notes:

```
sed '/^[0-9].*[0-9]$/d'
```

Would fail to delete the lines that contain a single digit (even though they start and end in a digit).

Also note that in many locales, `[0-9]` matches more than the `0123456789` digits. If you want to match on those only, you'd need `[0123456789]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

The more  obvious command to filter lines based on a pattern is `grep`.

`cat` is the command to concatenate. It makes little sense to concatenate a single file.

Here, to address all those and ignore any leading or trailing spacing characters (like the MS-DOS trailing carriage returns in your input), you could do:

```
<file.txt.in grep -e '^[[:space:]]*[^[:digit:][:space:]]' \
                  -e '[^[:digit:][:space:]][[:space:]]*$' \
                  -e '^[[:space:]]*$' > file.txt.out
```

(that is return the lines that start or  end in a non-digit (past the leading whitespace, or before the trailing whitespace), or are all whitespace.

Or:

```
<file.txt.in grep -vx '[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\(.*[[:digit:]]\)\{0,1\}[[:space:]]*' > file.txt.out
```

Or the same with EREs:

```
<file.txt.in grep -vxE '[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]](.*[[:digit:]])?[[:space:]]*' > file.txt.out
```

That is, filter *out* (with `-v`) the lines that start with a digit optionally followed by the rest a line ending in a digit, allowing whitespace at the start and ned.

Those ones could however fail to remove lines like `8xx<non-character>yy8` where `<non-character>` is a sequence of bytes that don't form a valid character in the current locale. But in any case, you can't expect much portably for this kind of line that is not valid text.

Answer (score 0):

If

`cat file1.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d' > file2.txt`

works, but

`cat file1.txt | sed '/^[0-9].*[0-9]$/d' > file2.txt`

doesn't (although one would expect to work like the former);

considering that input file might include Windows carriage returns,
then it might be safer to use this command instead:

`cat file1.txt | sed '/^[0-9].*[0-9]\(\r\|$\)/d' > file2.txt`

This should work in all cases, including lines ending with Linux or Windows carriage return.

Comment: `[$]` is a literal dollar sign, so the line `1$x` would be deleted by this command.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for the warning! Any suggestions for adding `\r` without using two commands?

Comment: Something like `\(\r\|$\)` (or `(\r|$)` for `sed -E`) maybe?

Comment: Note that `\s`, `\r` and `\|` are non-standard (originally GNU) extensions.